# How to insert a feed tile in XML view in sapui5.?/ How to bind or connect the controller.js(link i provided in controller) to xml view

Tags: xml, sapui5

xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"  xmlns:s="sap.m" xmlns ="sap.suite.ui.commons" controllerName="view.View1" >

```
    <l:HorizontalLayout class="sapUiSmallMargin" >





    <GenericTile class="sapUiSmallMargin" frameType="OneByOne" header="Browse by Industries" press="Press" size="M" width="auto">
        <tileContent>
            <TileContent footer="Packaged Solutions" size="M">
                <content>
                    <NumericContent icon="sap-icon://factory" size="M" value="143" valueColor="Error"/>
                </content>
            </TileContent>
        </tileContent>
    </GenericTile>
    <GenericTile class="sapUiSmallMargin" frameType="OneByOne" header="Browse by Technology" press="press" size="M" width="auto">
        <tileContent>
            <TileContent footer="Packaged Solutions" size="M">
                <content>
                    <NumericContent icon="sap-icon://energy-saving-lightbulb" size="M" value="53" valueColor="Error"/>
                </content>
            </TileContent>
        </tileContent>
    </GenericTile>
    <GenericTile class="sapUiSmallMargin" frameType="OneByOne" header="Browse by  Focus Topic" press="press" size="M" width="auto">
        <tileContent>
            <TileContent footer="Packaged Solutions" size="M">
                <content>
                    <NumericContent icon="sap-icon://globe" size="M" value="143" valueColor="Error"/>
                </content>
            </TileContent>
        </tileContent>
    </GenericTile>


    <GenericTile class="sapUiSmallMargin" frameType="OneByOne" header="A-Z Index" press="press" size="M" width="auto">
        <tileContent>
            <TileContent footer="Packaged Solutions" size="M">
                <content>
                    <NumericContent icon="sap-icon://list" size="M" value="143" valueColor="Error"/>
                </content>
            </TileContent>
        </tileContent>
    </GenericTile>
    </l:HorizontalLayout>

    <l:HorizontalLayout class="sapUiSmallMargin" >

    <GenericTile class="sapUiSmallMargin" frameType="OneByOne" header="Hot News" press="press" size="M" width="auto" headerImage="sap-icon://newspaper">
        <tileContent>
            <TileContent footer = "Packaged Solutions" size="M">
                <content>
                <NumericContent icon="sap-icon://list" size="M" value="143" valueColor="Error"/>    
                </content>
            </TileContent>
        </tileContent>
    </GenericTile>
    <GenericTile class="sapUiSmallMargin" frameType="OneByOne" header="Build and Publish Partner Solutions" press="press" size="M" width="auto" headerImage="sap-icon://action-settings">
        <tileContent>
            <TileContent size="M">
                <content>

                <NumericContent icon="sap-icon://list" size="M" value="143" valueColor="Error" />   
                </content>
            </TileContent>
        </tileContent>
    </GenericTile>







      </l:HorizontalLayout>





</s:Page>
```

In controller
how i have to..
 https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/suite/ui/commons/demokit/FeedTile.html

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? Right now it's not clear what you're after

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is... however, in your XML view you now display `GenericTiles`, not `FeedTiles`. Do you need FeedTiles instead?

Comment: yes  i need feed tiles in x ml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<FeedTile items="{/data}">
    <items>
        <FeedItem 
            title="{title}" 
            image="{img}" 
            link="{url}" 
            source="{src}" 
            publicationDate="{pubdate}" />
    </items>
</FeedTile>
```

A `FeedTile` has an aggregation `items` which takes a `FeedItem` as its template